# spring-framework v4.2.4.RELEASE test fails on RepeatedSpringRunnerTests

Tags: spring, gradle, build

I'm trying to run gradle test for v4.2.4.RELEASE of spring-framework

I'm running the tests using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31 and Gradle 2.5

I get the following stack trace below.
Any clue as to what might be going wrong ?

```
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] org.springframework.test.context.junit4.RepeatedSpringRunnerTests > assertRepetitions[TimedRepeatedTestCase] FAILED
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.AssertionError: tests failed for [class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.RepeatedSpringRunnerTests$TimedRepeatedTestCase]: expected:<3> but was:<2>
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.JUnitTestingUtils.runTestsAndAssertCounters(JUnitTestingUtils.java:97)
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.RepeatedSpringRunnerTests.assertRepetitions(RepeatedSpringRunnerTests.java:92)
```

Comment: Don't use gradle use the gradle wrapper contained within spring that way you are using the intended gradle version. (Which is 2.9 or 2.10 I believe and not 2.5). The Spring Framework ReadMe explains how to [build from sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework#compile-and-test-build-all-jars-distribution-zips-and-docs).

Comment: I get the same result running using gradlew test from the spring distribution on the command line.

Comment: The only way the RepeatedSpringRunnerTests pass is if I run the class as JUnit test within eclipse.  
Since the tests succeed/fail depending on their execution time if I understand the code,  
I don't see where the difference comes from between gradle / eclipse executions.

Answer (score 0):

Running clean test instead of simply test solves the problem.
Apparently the first time test is run the task succeeds.
But if run a second time it fails unless clean test is run instead.

Comment: ran into the problem again. solved it for good by building on a *nix system